# Добавление своего метода к произвольному объекту в powershell

Tags: powershell

Не могу сообразить, что ли я что-то делаю не так, то ли это в принципе нельзя сделать средствами powershell

Суть проблемы в следующем: нужно собрать множество записей в одну коллекцию, и после этого посчитать похожие, опираясь на один из параметров объекта находящимся в коллекции.

Для реализации данной задачи, решил сделать свой объект с несколькими свойствами (одно из этих свойств будет сравниваться для определения похожести объектов). Для коллекции решено использовать ArrayList.

А сама проблема оказалась в следующем: Добавляю динамически scriptmethod. Если целевой объект является PSObject, то никаких проблем, если же целевой объект является ArrayList, то код отрабатывает без ошибок, но метод не появляется у объекта. Пример рабочего кода:

```
$MyObject = New-Object PSObject
$myObject | Add-Member -Name "MyTest" -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value
{
if ($value -match "^\d+$") {echo "Число"} else {echo "Не число"}
}
$MyObject.MyTest("222")
```

В этом коде никаких проблем, все прекрасно отрабатывается.

В следующем коде все отрабатывается, но добавляемый метод не появляется:

```
[Collections.ArrayList]$MyArray = new-object Collections.ArrayList
$MyArray | Add-Member -Name "MyTest" -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value {
   Param([string]$value)
   echo $value
}
# предыдущие две строки нормально выполняются, никаких исключений не кидается
$MyArray.MyTest("222")
#Последняя строка выплевывает исключение об отсутствии метода MyTest
```

Отсюда вопросы, почему метод не добавился? Не уже ли нельзя добавить свой метод в Arraylist? Как поступить красиво при решении моей проблемы? (сделать отдельную функцию с двумя аргументами: листа и значения - не хочется, мне кажется это некрасивое решение...

**Заранее спасибо за Вашу помощь**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нашел решения вопроса в том виде, как я хотел. Решил все данные собрать, не анализируя дубликаты в момент добавления (к сожалению потребовалось достаточно много ресурсов для этого списка). А дальше массив с формированными классами прогнал через

```
Group-Object | 
Where-Object | 
Foreach-Object
```

Группировка происходила достаточно долго, но что поделать... Проблема решена, хоть и не самым оптимальным путем.